# Django get data from get method and pass to post method

Tags: python, django, post, get

I am trying to pass the data from get method to post method, so I can update my database data through a form. In below code, specifically I tried to use a class level variable "saved_objectID" to pass the editObjectID from get method to post method. But I always get blank values/no value.

Is there a way to implement this? Thank you in advance for the help

```
class EditDataView(ListView):
    model =TemporaryModel
    form_class = TemporaryForm
    template_name = 'frontend/editData.html'
    dict = { "EditData":"Edit Data Below"}
    saved_objectID = ''

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        editObjectId = request.GET.get('editObjectId')
        editObjects = TemporaryModel.objects.get(pk=editObjectId)
        saved_objectID = editObjectId
        form = TemporaryForm(instance=editObjects)
        return render(request, 'frontend/editData.html', {'form': form,"dict":dict})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = TemporaryForm(request.POST, instance=TemporaryModel.objects.get(pk=self.saved_objectID))
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'frontend/editData.html', {'form': form,"dict":dict})
```

Comment: in get() use self.saved_objectID = editObjectId but not sure if class instance will be available for different calls

Comment: You can persist data between requests from the same anonymous browser session using django's built-in sessions framework. Have you tried that? There are examples in the django docs:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/#examples

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how you deploy your django application. I guess in your case, you http server use `process` to serve the user requests.

So, the two different user action `get` & `post` are in two different processes, although `saved_objectID` are both the class member of `EditDataView`, but the two `EditDataView` in two different python process. So, you cannot get the value.

Typically, don't make two different requests communicate by a variable in memory, even it can stay in the same process because you change http server deploy mode, you still can not get ride of other interfere(e.g. other user request's sequence).

For your scenario, why not just return the `saved_objectID` to user's brower using `hidden variable`? Or if you care about security, you can also use `redis`, store the `saved_objectID` as a value in `redis` and return the key to user's browser.

In a word, don't use variable in memory to communicate, you can assure nothing in a multi-process environment, find a standalone product if you really need it.

Comment: The redis solution seems seems similar to what's already possible with django's default sessions framework. You can use redis or memcached as a storage backend for server side session data.

Comment: Yes, session also a good solution. Just, if the user open 2 posts to edit together in one browser. Use session may need to handle different key names by programmer self to avoid conflict of 2 candidate posts, as user's action maybe `GET`->`GET`->`POST`->`POST`

Comment: Thank you atline and Haken very much for the help. I never used redis before, will try it and come back to report the result.